i want to create two classes (invoice,invoice details) from gridview
i have sheet excel contain fileds (invoiceid, date, customer, amount, note) and i want to make two classes to create invoice header (ID, Date, Customer, total, paid, remaining) and invoice details (invoiceid, note, quantity=1, amount)
using DevExpress.XtraEditors;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;

namespace ImportExcelToGridView
{
    public partial class frm_ImportData : XtraForm
    {
        public frm_ImportData()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frm_ImportData_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            gv_excel.OptionsBehavior.Editable = false;
            btn_Import.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void btn_SelectFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
            op.Filter = "Excel Sheet(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
            if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                lbl_Filepath.Text = op.FileName;
            string filePath = lbl_Filepath.Text;
            string constr = string.Empty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lbl_Filepath.Text))
            {
                if (filePath.EndsWith(".xls"))
                    constr = String.Format("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.4.0;" + @"Data Source = {0}; Extended Properties ='Excel 8.0;HDR=yes'", filePath);
                else
                    constr = String.Format("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + @"Data Source = {0}; Extended Properties ='Excel 8.0;HDR=yes'", filePath);
                btn_Import.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
                btn_Import.Enabled = false;
            OleDbConnection exCon = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            exCon.Open();
            cmb_Sheets.DataSource = exCon.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            cmb_Sheets.DisplayMember = "Table_Name";
            cmb_Sheets.ValueMember = "Table_Name";
            exCon.Close();
        }

        private void lbl_View_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gv_excel.Columns.Clear();
            string filePath = lbl_Filepath.Text;
            string constr = string.Empty;
            if (filePath.EndsWith(".xls"))
                constr = String.Format("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.4.0;" + @"Data Source = {0}; Extended Properties ='Excel 8.0;HDR=yes'", filePath);
            else
                constr = String.Format("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + @"Data Source = {0}; Extended Properties ='Excel 8.0;HDR=yes'", filePath);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + cmb_Sheets.Text + "" + "]", constr);
            da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Table");
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            gc_excel.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            //Classes.InvoiceForm(gr);
        }

        private void btn_CreateInvices_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //I have sheet excel contain fileds (Invoice,Name,Date,Amount,Note) i import this in datagridview
            //i want to make tow class tables and join between them
            //1-Invoice header(id=invoice,date=date,Company=txt_Company,Branch=txt_Branch,custmer=name,total&paid&net=total,remaining=0)
            //2-invoice details(Inv_ID=invoice, Note=note, Price=amount, Qty=1)
        }


        public class InvoiceHeader
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public string Company { get; set; }
            public string Branch { get; set; }
            public string Customer { get; set; }
            public float Total { get; set; }
            public float Paid { get; set; }
            public float Remaining { get; set; }
            public float Net { get; set; }
            public List<InvoiceDetails> Subjects { get; private set; }
        }

        public class InvoiceDetails
        {
            public int Inv_ID { get; set; }
            public string Note { get; set; }
            public float Price { get; set; }
            public float Qty { get; set; }
        }


        private void btn_Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rpt_Invoice_A5.Print(gc_excel.DataSource);
        }
    }
}

i import sheet data to gridcontrol then i cannot build classes
i have sheet excel contain fileds (invoiceid, date, customer, amount, note) and i want to make two classes to create invoice header (ID, Date, Customer, total, paid, remaining) and invoice details (invoiceid, note, quantity=1, amount)
